# Firebase integration with React-Native IOS app is failing

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I am trying to integrate the Firebase service with React-Native framework.
I am trying to follow this tutorial in Udemy: https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-react-native-and-redux-course/

Steps I followed:

1. Downloaded firebase using npm command:  npm install --save react-native-firebase
2. Created a project in the firebase console.
3. Pasted the config created by Firebase in the React-native code.

   class App extends Component {

   ```
   componentWillMount() {
   firebase.initializeApp({
       apiKey: 'AIzaSyAMuW4adFuW_XoYvpvke_iHTvlAkuVJ7Fk',
       authDomain: 'authproj2.firebaseapp.com',
       databaseURL: 'https://authproj2.firebaseio.com',
       projectId: 'authproj2',
       storageBucket: 'authproj2.appspot.com',
       messagingSenderId: '654736603029'
     });

   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
       if(user)
       {
           this.setState( {loggedIn:true} );
       }
       else {
           this.setState( {loggedIn: false } );
       }
   });
   ```

   }
   }

And in a different React component I am creating a a Login Form which has a Submit button.

The onButtonPress function is :

```
    onButtonPress () {
    const { email , password } = this.state;

    this.setState({error: '', loading: true});

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
    .catch(() => {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
        .catch(this.onLoginFailure.bind(this));
    });
    }
```

These are the onLoginSuccess and OnLoginFailure functions:

```
onLoginSuccess () {
this.setState( {email:'', password:'', error:'', loading:false});
```

}

```
onLoginFailure () {
this.setState( {error: "Authentication Failure!!", loading:false } );
```

}

But when I click on the button no action takes place. Ideally it should create an a new account if the email and password are entered for the first time and show a different page if the email and password are correct.
But somewhere the integration of Firebase with React-native is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using web SDK which requires `firebase` package but you have got `react-native-firebase` package installed.

If you want to go ahead with the code and firebase you have written then you should install [firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) package.

**To solve your problem you should install `firebase` package**

However to properly leverage firebase in mobile environment, it is recommended to use `react-native-firebase` but in that case, the `firebase.initializeApp({` becomes meaningless as the firebase initialization in mobile happens using `Google-services.json` and `Google-services.plist` files provided by firebase console in android and iOS respectively when using the `react-native-firebase` package.

If you want to go with react-native-firebase please refer [this](https://rnfirebase.io/).

Comment: Just ran the command: npm install --save firebase inside the Project.
But its still not working.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iXAi-az5MMTlVjItQNFWvzcKBNY7sDjj
The above link has the path to my React-Native project.

Comment: Have seen your code and executed it, he problem now with the code is you have not passed a valid prop for your `Button` component . When you are pressing the button on LoginForm. It does not respond because the Button component which you have made is expecting a `whenPressed` prop and you have passed `onPress` replace that with `whenPressed` and your code will start to execute atleast and then you will be able to debug your code properly. Also `firebase` package is also the one which is required for the code you have written so the answer written above made sense :)

Comment: Hi, Sorry for late reply. The answer in the comment worked for me.
thanks :)

Comment: Hi, I made the above changes, that worked for me. But when I click on the button it gives me an error message, which I displayed as part of AuthenticationFailure.
That means the code to sign-in through firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword is not working. Can you help me with that?
One more thing, whenever I make an entry in the textbox, will it create an entry in the firebase console or is it a local firebase database getting created?